# How to use redobackup without free partition

Tags: partition, backup, virtual-machine, ntfs

I had a spare 250GB drive a while ago from an old Windows Vista computer. There wasn't much data on the drive. I wanted to use it for a new OS in my computer, and I was in a rush to use it, so I backed up the partition with [Redo Backup](http://redobackup.org/) to a folder on my current NTFS drive. It didn't work right away, and I ended up having 3 folders worth of backup data, each about 30GB.

When I tried to restore it in VMware or Virtualbox to a virtual disk, there were a lot of "write errors". Is there a way to transfer these backup files to a virtual disk file?  Any way (Windows, Linux, Livecd, VM) is good, but I'm trying not to use free space, so a solution that doesn't require a lot of working space would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

The `.img` files appear to be usable by VirtualBox and/or VMware. According to this article titled: [Converting a Clonezilla Image to a VirtualBox, KVM, or VMWare Virtual Machine Image](http://www.hyperionworks.com/blog/4/converting-a-clonezilla-image-to-a-virtualbox-kvm-or-vmware-virtual-machine-image).

In that article it's mentioned that you can use tools such as VBoxManage, qemu-img, vdiskmanager to convert the the `.img` file to the virtual machine image of your choice.